# Stopwatch unpause doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener

I'm trying to create a stopwatch. The **start** and **pause** buttons works fine but the **unpause** button doesn't work properly.
**timer** is my JLabel in which I want to ilustrate my stopwatch (it references **timer** from the JFrame). I can't post a MCVE because it's too much code.

Here is my **Stopwatch** class:

```
public class Stopwatch extends Thread {

    private boolean finishedFlag = false;
    private boolean pauseFlag = false;
    private boolean sortFlag = false;
    private long summedTime = 0;
    private JLabel timer;

    public Stopwatch(){}

    public Stopwatch(boolean finished, boolean pause, boolean sort, JLabel timer){
        this.finishedFlag = finished;
        this.pauseFlag = pause;
        this.sortFlag = sort;
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(sortFlag && !pauseFlag && !finishedFlag) {
            update(summedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
        if(pauseFlag)
            summedTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        else 
            summedTime = 0;
    }

    private void update(long dT){
        long x = (dT/1000)%60;
        long y = (dT/60000)%1000;
        if(x>=0 && x<=9 && y>=0 && y<=9)
            timer.setText("0"+String.valueOf((dT/60000)%1000)+":0"+String.valueOf((dT/1000)%60)+","+String.valueOf((dT)%1000));
        else if(x>9 && y>=0 && y<=9)
            timer.setText("0"+String.valueOf((dT/60000)%1000)+":"+String.valueOf((dT/1000)%60)+","+String.valueOf((dT)%1000));
        else if(x>=0 && x<=9 && y>9)
            timer.setText(String.valueOf((dT/60000)%1000)+":0"+String.valueOf((dT/1000)%60)+","+String.valueOf((dT)%1000));
        else if(x>9 && y>9)
            timer.setText(String.valueOf((dT/60000)%1000)+":"+String.valueOf((dT/1000)%60)+","+String.valueOf((dT)%1000));
    }
}
```

This are the listeners I use for my buttons:

```
ActionListener sortListener = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(sortFlag == false && pauseFlag == false)
            {
                sortFlag = true;
                System.out.println("sort");
                stopwatch1 = new Stopwatch(finishedFlag,pauseFlag,sortFlag,timer1);
                stopwatch1.start();
                appFrame.validate();
                appFrame.repaint();
            }
        }
    };
    sortButton.addActionListener(sortListener);

    ActionListener pauseListener = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(sortFlag && pauseFlag == false)
            {
                pauseFlag = true;
                timeSpent = stopwatch1.getSummedTime();
                stopwatch1.setPauseFlag(true);
                System.out.println("pause");
            }
        }
    };
    pauseButton.addActionListener(pauseListener);

    ActionListener unpauseListener = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(sortFlag && pauseFlag)
            {
                pauseFlag = false;
                stopwatch1.setPauseFlag(false);
                stopwatch1.run();
                System.out.println("unpause");
            }
        }
    };
    unpauseButton.addActionListener(unpauseListener);
```

Comment: You need to place a monitor lock inside you main loop

Comment: You mean in the while loop from the run() method? Lock it when the pause button is clicked and unlock it when the unpause button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need someway to pause the `Thread` and stop the update from occurring.  You could do this with an `if` statement inside your `run` loop, but there is a more efficient way through the use of monitor lock

```
public class Stopwatch extends Thread {
    //...
    private final Object pauseLock;

    public Stopwatch() {
        pauseLock = new Object();
    }

    public Stopwatch(boolean finished, boolean pause, boolean sort, JLabel timer) {
        this();
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (sortFlag && !finishedFlag) {
            while (pauseFlag) {
                synchronized (pauseLock) {
                    try {
                        pauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                }
            }
            update(summedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        }
        if (pauseFlag) {
            summedTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        } else {
            summedTime = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now, you need some way to pause and resume the `run` loop

```
public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
    if (paused && !pauseFlag) {
        pauseFlag = paused;
    } else if (!paused && pauseFlag) {
        pauseFlag = paused;
        synchronized (pauseLock) {
            pauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, however, we have bigger problem, Swing is NOT thread safe.  This means that your `update` method is breaking the single thread rules of Swing and could cause no end of issues...

A simpler solution would be to just use a Swing `Timer`

[image: Swing Timer]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;
        private StopWatch sw;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label, gbc);

            sw = new StopWatch(label);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Resume");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    sw.setPaused(!sw.isPaused());
                    btn.setText(sw.isPaused() ? "Resume" : "Pause");
                }
            });
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

    }

    public class StopWatch {

        private Timer timer;
        private JLabel label;

        private int runningTime;
        private long tickTime;

        public StopWatch(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
            timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    runningTime += (System.currentTimeMillis() - tickTime);
                    System.out.println(runningTime);
                    update(runningTime);
                    tickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            });
        }

        public void setPaused(boolean paused) {
            if (paused && timer.isRunning()) {
                timer.stop();
            } else if (!paused && !timer.isRunning()) {
                tickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timer.start();
            }
        }

        public boolean isPaused()  {
            return !timer.isRunning();
        }

        private void update(long dT) {
            long x = (dT / 1000) % 60;
            long y = (dT / 60000) % 1000;
            if (x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9) {
                label.setText("0" + String.valueOf((dT / 60000) % 1000) + ":0" + String.valueOf((dT / 1000) % 60) + "," + String.valueOf((dT) % 1000));
            } else if (x > 9 && y >= 0 && y <= 9) {
                label.setText("0" + String.valueOf((dT / 60000) % 1000) + ":" + String.valueOf((dT / 1000) % 60) + "," + String.valueOf((dT) % 1000));
            } else if (x >= 0 && x <= 9 && y > 9) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf((dT / 60000) % 1000) + ":0" + String.valueOf((dT / 1000) % 60) + "," + String.valueOf((dT) % 1000));
            } else if (x > 9 && y > 9) {
                label.setText(String.valueOf((dT / 60000) % 1000) + ":" + String.valueOf((dT / 1000) % 60) + "," + String.valueOf((dT) % 1000));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

See [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Can you please tell me how can i get the time when i click stop?