# create a java gui countdown timer that starts with user input

Tags: java, swing, timer

**Here is the github** [link](https://github.com/syedsadman16/CountdownTimer)

So I was trying to create an application and broke it down into 3 parts, one of which is to create a timer. This timer has two fields: one to input minutes and one to input seconds. It is supposed to take in minutes or seconds typed in by the user and display a countdown on the application screen. When the timer reaches 0, it alerts the user. I have searched everywhere and could not find a countdown timer in Java that does that. All I found were countdown timers that work in console or countdown timers that already have predefined values set by the developer, not user.

I wanted to make a timer just like this one from google: 
 [Google Timer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztR2T.png)

P.s. I am a new self-taught programmer. This is my second java project so I don't have much experience yet. Looking forward to any help :)

Here is my code:

```
public class TestPane extends JFrame {

private LocalDateTime startTime;
private JLabel timerLabel;
private Timer timer;
private JButton startbtn;
private JTextField timeSet;
int count;
int count_2;
private Duration duration;
private JTextField minSet;
private JTextField secSet;


public TestPane() {


    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(400,400);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new CardLayout(0, 0));

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(panel, "name_87856346254020");
    panel.setLayout(null);

    timerLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    timerLabel.setBounds(59, 48, 194, 14);
    panel.add(timerLabel);

    startbtn = new JButton("New button");
    startbtn.setBounds(124, 187, 89, 23);
    panel.add(startbtn);

    timeSet = new JTextField(1);
    timeSet.setBounds(106, 85, 86, 20);
    panel.add(timeSet);
    timeSet.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblHours = new JLabel("Hours");
    lblHours.setBounds(29, 88, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblHours);

    JLabel lblMinss = new JLabel("Mins");
    lblMinss.setBounds(29, 114, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblMinss);

    JLabel lblSecs = new JLabel("Secs");
    lblSecs.setBounds(29, 139, 46, 14);
    panel.add(lblSecs);

    minSet = new JTextField(60);
    minSet.setBounds(75, 116, 86, 20);
    panel.add(minSet);
    minSet.setColumns(10);

    secSet = new JTextField();
    secSet.setBounds(75, 147, 86, 20);
    panel.add(secSet);
    secSet.setColumns(10);


    startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                 startbtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timeSet.getText().trim();
                if(timeSet.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    duration = Duration.ofMinutes(count_min);
                } else {
                count_hour = Integer.parseInt(timeSet.getText());                   
                duration = Duration.ofHours(count_hour);                
                }

                minSet.getText().trim();                                
                if(minSet.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    duration = Duration.ofHours(count_hour);
                } else {
                    count_min = Integer.parseInt(minSet.getText());
                    duration = Duration.ofMinutes(count_min);                   
                }

                secSet.getText().trim();
                if(secSet.getText().isEmpty() && minSet.getText().isEmpty()) {
                duration = Duration.ofHours(count_hour);        
                } 
                else if(secSet.getText().isEmpty() && timeSet.getText().isEmpty()){
                    duration = Duration.ofMinutes(count_sec);
                }
                else {                  
                    count_sec = Integer.parseInt(secSet.getText());
                    duration = duration.ofSeconds(count_sec);
                }


                if (timer.isRunning()) {
                    timer.stop();
                    startTime = null;
                    startbtn.setText("Start");
                } 
                else {
                    startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                    timer.start();
                    startbtn.setText("Stop");
                }

            }
        });           

        timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, now);
                Duration timeLeft = duration.minus(runningTime);
                if (timeLeft.isZero() || timeLeft.isNegative()) {
                    timeLeft = Duration.ZERO;
                    startbtn.doClick(); // Cheat
                }

                timerLabel.setText(format(timeLeft));
            }
        });
    }

    protected String format(Duration duration) {
        long hours = duration.toHours();
        long mins = duration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();
        long seconds = (duration.minusMinutes(mins).toMillis() / 1000) %60;
        return String.format("%02dh %02dm %02ds", hours, mins, seconds);
    }   


    public static void main(String args[]){        
        new TestPane();
    }
}
```

**Update:** 
So far, when the user sets hours and leaves minutes and seconds blank, it counts down from hours. Same with seconds. However, I cannot get the minutes to do the same. If I leave everything blank except for minutes, the timer does nothing. Also, I want to make the timer work simultaneously with hours, minutes and seconds. As of now, it only works with one unit at a time.

[image]

Comment: You can reverse the concept, so you have a start time and a duration, let the `Timer` tick at a regular interval, say half a second, and check to see if the timer has been running for the specified period. You can easily generate the countdown time by subtracting the running time from the duration

Comment: As an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337718/java-swing-timer-countdown/28338476#28338476) - Remember, most time operations occur at the millisecond level, so you need to convert you input to milliseconds. You might also want to have a look at [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)

Comment: Add a slightly more complex [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714257/i-dont-know-how-to-display-timer-when-stopped/35714415#35714415)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the links. This is my second project in Java so I guess I need to start small.

Comment: This `Duration.ofHours(count);` does nothing

Comment: `int count = Integer.parseInt(timeSet.getText());` is causing your NPE because `timeSet` has not been initialised yet. You need to pick this information up in the `ActionListener` for the` startBtn`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the basic idea is to start with a Swing `Timer`.  It's safe to use it to update the UI, won't block the UI thread and can repeat at a regular interval.  See [How to use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

Because all timers only guarantee a minimum duration (that is, they could wait longer then the specified delay), you can't rely on updating a state value simply by adding the expected duration.  Instead, you need to be able to calculate the difference in time between to points in time.

For this, I would use the Date/Time API introduced in Java 8.  See [Period and Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html) and [Date and Time Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) for more details.

From there, it's a simple matter of setting up a `Timer`, calculating the `Duration` from the start time to now and formatting the result

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private LocalDateTime startTime;
        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label, gbc);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                        startTime = null;
                        btn.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                        timer.start();
                        btn.setText("Stop");
                    }
                }
            });
            add(btn, gbc);

            timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                    Duration duration = Duration.between(startTime, now);
                    label.setText(format(duration));
                }
            });
        }

        protected String format(Duration duration) {
            long hours = duration.toHours();
            long mins = duration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();
            long seconds = duration.minusMinutes(mins).toMillis() / 1000;
            return String.format("%02dh %02dm %02ds", hours, mins, seconds);
        }

    }


}
```

## Countdown timer...

> This timer counts up. How would I get it to count down instead? I tried putting in code from your links but it wouldn't work. The documentations didn't help me understand much either.

This requires a slightly better understanding of the Date/Time API.

Basically, you need to know the expected duration (how long the timer should run for) and the amount of time the timer has been running. From this, you can calculate the amount of time remaining (the countdown)

For simplicity, I started with a `Duration` of 5 minutes...

```
private Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes(5);
```

Each time the `Timer` ticked, I simply calculated the running time and calculate the remaining time...

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, now);
Duration timeLeft = duration.minus(runningTime);
if (timeLeft.isZero() || timeLeft.isNegative()) {
    timeLeft = Duration.ZERO;
    // Stop the timer and reset the UI
}
```

All I really did was played around with the API.  I knew I would need a `Duration` in the end (as that's what I was formatting) so I wanted to keep that.  Since I also needed a "duration" of time, to represent the length of time the `Timer` should run for, the `Duration` class seemed like a good place to start.

I had thought I might need to calculate the difference `between` the two `Duration`s (like I did for the `runningTime`), but as it turns out, all I really wanted was the difference between them (ie subtraction of one from the other).

All that was left was to add a check to ensure that the `Timer` doesn't run into negative time and you know have a concept of a "time out" or "count down" timer.

When you're dealing with these kinds of problems, its always a good thing to start out with a "core concept" of how it "might" work - ie, start by figuring out how you might count down in seconds. This gives you some ground work, from there, you can see what support the API provides and how you might use it to your advantage.  In this case, `Duration` was super easy and continued to provide support for the formatting of the output

For example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private LocalDateTime startTime;
        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;

        private Duration duration = Duration.ofMinutes(5);

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            label = new JLabel("...");
            add(label, gbc);

            JButton btn = new JButton("Start");
            btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (timer.isRunning()) {
                        timer.stop();
                        startTime = null;
                        btn.setText("Start");
                    } else {
                        startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
                        timer.start();
                        btn.setText("Stop");
                    }
                }
            });
            add(btn, gbc);

            timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
                    Duration runningTime = Duration.between(startTime, now);
                    Duration timeLeft = duration.minus(runningTime);
                    if (timeLeft.isZero() || timeLeft.isNegative()) {
                        timeLeft = Duration.ZERO;
                        btn.doClick(); // Cheat
                    }

                    label.setText(format(timeLeft));
                }
            });
        }

        protected String format(Duration duration) {
            long hours = duration.toHours();
            long mins = duration.minusHours(hours).toMinutes();
            long seconds = duration.minusMinutes(mins).toMillis() / 1000;
            return String.format("%02dh %02dm %02ds", hours, mins, seconds);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting me started! I need to get user input and start the countdown from what the user specifies in a JTextField. I just cant figure out how to do that.

Comment: I would suggest that when the start button is triggered, you read the values from the text field at that point

Comment: This timer counts up. How would I get it to count down instead? I tried putting in code from your links but it wouldn't work. The documentations didn't help me understand much either.

Comment: You need - a duration (how long the timer should run for); the current amount of time the timer has been running (you already have this); you then simply need to calculate the difference between the two. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28337718/java-swing-timer-countdown/28338476#28338476) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35714257/i-dont-know-how-to-display-timer-when-stopped/35714415#35714415) for example

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I had a problem with hours and seconds. I found that if I set hours, the timer would countdown using seconds, not hours. However, I was able to fix that problem by adding this:                                          
       long seconds = (duration.minusMinutes(mins).toMillis() / 1000) %60;

Comment: @SyedSadman `int count = Integer.parseInt(timeSet.getText());` is causing your NPE because `timeSet` has not been initialised yet. You need to pick this information up in the `ActionListener` for the` startBtn`

Comment: Alright so I got the timer working for either hours,minutes or seconds. I want it to work for all three so I added three textfields which take each. However, the program gives errors when I leave a box blank. For example, If I put a number in the hours box but not the other ones,it wont work. I tried if and else statements and also tried having preset values in the boxes. The program doesn't work the way it should. Any ideas on how I can have the user input either hours, minutes or seconds or all and make it work together?

Comment: You'll need to supply a default value for when a value is blank.  Use `String#trim` to remove blank spaces, then check it's length and determine if the value is empty or not, if it is, supply a default value of `0`

Comment: So I tried what you said and it worked. Hours and seconds works individually but when I put Minutes, it just shows up as 00:00:00 when I enter a time. I updated my code above.

Comment: Can you please tell after stop and again start how can i start from previous stopped time instead of starting from beginning?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to start the time again from previous stopped time.Now its starting from 0

Comment: @SachinHR You want a [stopwatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596286/stopwatch-unpause-doesnt-work/29596338?r=SearchResults#29596338)