# Thread not stopping after GUI button press

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface

I have a program that's supposed to have a GUI where you input values in a text box and it counts down as a timer. A thread handles the countdown and a stop button should stop the countdown. I have a boolean that sets whether the loop runs or not. The problem is, any effort made by the buttons to change the value is ignored. When the button is pressed, the boolean is set to true, but if I check it again afterwards it goes back to false. I don't get how or why this happens.

This is the countdown method.

```
class countClockDown implements Runnable
    {
        int hour, min, sec, mili;
        volatile boolean stop = false;
        countClockDown()
        {
        }
        void setCountClockDown(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            hour = a;
            min = b;
            sec = c;
        }
        
        void setCountClockDown(int a, int b, int c, int d)
        {
            hour = a;
            min = b;
            sec = c;
            mili = d;
        }
        void stopRunning()
        {
            stop = true;
        }
        public void run()
        {
            while(!stop && (hour != 0 | min != 0 | sec > 0 | mili > 0))
            {
                Thread.yield();
                if (mili < 0)
                {
                    mili = 999;
                    sec--;
                }
                if (sec < 0)
                {
                    sec = 59;
                    min--;
                }
                if (min < 0)
                {
                    min = 59;
                    hour--;
                }
                mili--;
                
                countHRIn.setText(String.valueOf(hour));
                countMINIn.setText(String.valueOf(min));
                countSECIn.setText(String.valueOf(sec));
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }
            
        
    }
```

This is the button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        int hour, min, sec, mil;
        Object source = ae.getSource();
        countClockDown cd = new countClockDown();
        countClockUp cu = new countClockUp();
        Thread t = new Thread(cd);
        
        if (source == countStart)
        {
            hour = Integer.parseInt(countHRIn.getText());
            min = Integer.parseInt(countMINIn.getText());
            sec = Integer.parseInt(countSECIn.getText());
            cd.setCountClockDown(hour, min, sec);
            t.start();
        }
        
        if (source == countStop)
        {
            cd.stop = true;
            t.interrupt();
            System.out.print(cd.stop);
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: every time you execute actionPerformed(...) you create a new cd. Is that really what you want when action is countStop? In other words you always operate on a new cd, due to countClockDown cd = new countClockDown();

Comment: All modifications to state of GUI components done in your threads have to be wrapped into `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`

Comment: You'd probably get a better result using a Swing `Timer` ... and it'd be easy to use - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596286/stopwatch-unpause-doesnt-work/29596338#29596338) and even a [decoupled concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408678/adding-resume-function-to-stopwatch/50409049#50409049)